# How can I fix the "Unhandled Rejection (error): Network error" obtained using axios in React

Tags: reactjs, api, .net-core, axios, localhost

I'm creating a React Application, and it is hosted on localhost:3000. I want to fetch data from a .NET Core Application hosted on localhost:5001. I'm using axios library to make http requests.

The function in which I make the request is:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await axios.get("http://localhost:5001/api/gateways");
    console.log(data);
  }
```

The obtained Error is "Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network Error".

I tried to test the API with Postman and it works, as well as accessing it from the browser and it works too.

At the same time I tried to consume data from another API, this time hosted on an online server, and it worked perfectly, that means, the problem must be between two applications hosted on the localhost.

Comment: Surround the asynchronous code in a `try/catch` so any rejected promises are caught and handled.

Comment: You are using https in localhost.

Comment: When I change the url to http:localhost does not work

Comment: did you reviewed the cors of your API? @doDDy

Comment: While whitelisting the port in .NET you must be using HTTPS. change it to HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding an Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header to HTTP responses in .NET CORE application. This header tells the browser that the server allows credentials for a cross-origin request.

Its necessary modify *Configure* method at Startup.cs fileadding the following code:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                await next.Invoke();
            });
```

And, it is also necessary modify *ConfigureServices* method with:

```
services.AddCors(c =>
            {
                c.AddDefaultPolicy(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod());
            });
```